# How to kill node inspector once you have started debugging

Tags: node.js, debugging, web-inspector, node-inspector

See screenshot below. How can I kill node inspector from the browser debugging environment (it won't let me kill it from the command line). The only thing I have succeeded at doing is clicking the "remove all breakpoints" button and then hitting "play", but this is not necessarily very effective.

How can I kill the debugging env quickly from either the command line or the browser (preferably the latter).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I normally do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> in the terminal, then click `Play` in the browser (so Node can handle the signal).

There's probably an easier way.

Comment: It won't always accept a Ctrl-C command, that's the problem :(